# How to store looped paired values into an array or object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, coordinates

I need to get **x, y values** of the each "**.spot**" element and **store into array or object**. This is what I have done so far.

```
function getPosition() {
    let loc = document.getElementsByClassName("spot");

    for (let i = 0; i < loc.length; i++) {
        let offsets = loc[i].getBoundingClientRect();
        let id = loc[i].id;
        let y = offsets.top;
        let x = offsets.left;

        drawLines(x, y);
    }
}

function drawLines(x, y) {

    //store values in a array or object
}
```

Comment: how the array will look like

Comment: @brk It doesn't matter for me. I need to draw lines between those points. Ideally,

[x1, y1, x2, y2, ...]

Comment: check below snippet 
it will give object array[{x:0,y:2},{x:1,y:5}]

Comment: more information is needed like what will be the keys and their value

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet

```
 var store=[];

    function drawLines(x, y) {

        var data={};
            data.x=x;
            data.y=y;
            store.push(data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **ES6** Syntax, you could do this.

```
let data = [];

function drawLines(x, y) {
   data.push({x, y});
}
```

This would form an array of objects with x and y as its properties.

Answer (score 0):

better use closure rather defining the variable globally.

```
let drawLines = ((x, y) => {
  let store = [];
  return (x, y) => {store.push({x: x, y: y}); return store;}
})();
```

or you can have only one function to return the array of objects.

```
function getPosition() {
    let locs = document.getElementsByClassName("spot");
    return locs.map((loc) => {
      let offsets = loc.getBoundingClientRect();
      let id = loc[i].id;
      return {x: offsets.left, y: offsets.top};
    });
 }
```